# PropertyGrid ExpandableObjectConverter Collection property List(Of T) with constructor and ReadOnly property

Tags: vb.net, typeconverter

I have a type that is used in a Generic List that has a constructor parameter that is the list itself.
E.g.

```
Class MyCollection(Of T)
    Inherits List(Of T)

    ...
End Class
```

And the actual class used for T is declared as:

```
Class MyClass
    Private _Parent As MyCollection
    Private _Property1 As String
    Private _Property2 As String

    Public Sub New(Parent As MyCollection, Property1 As String)
        _Parent = Parent
        Me.Property1 = Property1
    End Sub
    ...
    Public Property Property1 As String
        Get
            Return _Property1
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Property1 = value
            Dim result As String = value
            For Each item in Parent
                If item Is Me Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                ...
            Next
            _Property2 = result
       End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Property2 As String
        Get
            Return _Property2
       End Get
   End Property
End Class
```

How do I implement such a TypeConvertor to be used in a PropertyGrid.
My Parent property is not exposed as I do not use it other than in the class itself and my Property2 is ReadOnly. So in my PropertyGrid designer at runtime I do not want to see Parent and I do want to see Property2 but it should be read-only. If I do not use a TypeConverter at all this is the case, so why when I use a TypeConverter it does not work like I want it to. Without a typeconverter adding a new item does not work well at least I get an error saying "Contructor on Type 'MyClass' not found" so I assumed I needed to override the CreateInstance and GetCreateInstanceSupported methods. Even if I create a Property for my Parent property and set the Browsable attribute to False then my CreateInstance method has no where to find the Parent as it is not there in the propertyValues. If Instead expose it and set the ReadOnly attribute it is seen and it is also editable which I do not want. And the same for my Property2 I do not want it editable in the PropertyGrid. ReadOnly seems to be ignored. Do I also need a TypeConverter for my MyCollection class or do I need to override other methods??!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems I am probably stating the obvious answer as I am guessing the obvious answer always gets overlooked. I had to expose my list as a global variable. So in my code I say:

```
Class MyClass
    Private _Parent As MyCollection = Nothing
    ...
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Private ReadOnly Property Parent As MyCollection
        Get
            If _Parent Is Nothing Then
                _Parent = Module1.GlobalParent
            End If
            Return _Parent
        End Get
    End Prpoerty
    ...
    Public Property Property1 As String
        Get
            Return _Property1
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Property1 = value
            Dim result As String = value
            For Each item in Parent
                If item Is Me Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                ...
            Next
            _Property2 = result
       End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Property2 As String
        Get
            Return _Property2
       End Get
    End Property
    ...
End Class
```

I.e. not necessary to have a custom TypeConverter after all and lucky for me my module, form and class are in the same project otherwise life would be difficult!